# thymeleaf css Spring MVC annotation

Tags: css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Stylesheet do not work in my project. I am using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Config in my project.
My structure [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrKjb.png)

My login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/static/login.css}" href="../static/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" action="#"   method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My Stylesheet Login.css

```css
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
}
```

My Controller

`@Controller
public class UserController {`

```
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {

    return "login";
}
```

}`

My config file

`@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc //mvc:annotation-driven
@ComponentScan({ "controller" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{`

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
    // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);

    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    // templates to be automatically updated when modified.

    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
    // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
    // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
    // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
    // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
    // for safer backwards compatibility.
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return viewResolver;
}


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

}`
[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iobse.png)
The result is wrong. Login.css is not work. Where is mistake?

Comment: What's the generated path to login.css also check console errors

Comment: WARN 5764 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/static/login.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your Controller with @RequestMapping(**path** = "/"...

Although not very intuitive, but improper setting of this annotation can cause not loading of CSS.
I had similar problem and everything seemed correct (HTML, Thymeleaf code, project structure - I read a lot previous posts about that), but CSS wasn't there.